# Use case scenario based on a use case using "uses" or "extends"

Tags: design, uml, use-case

In a use case diagram, use case A "uses" use case B. I need to write the scenario based on steps of use case A. Since A  "uses" B, I just wanted to confirm that I need to include the steps of B inside A as well. Depending on what B exactly does, steps of B may be incorporated in steps of A in any order. Am I right?

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1696927/whats-is-the-difference-between-include-and-extend-in-use-case-diagram

Comment: Thanks, I am specifically looking into how to write steps of a scenario. I think I have a general understanding of uses and extends.

Answer (score 2):

> I just wanted to confirm that I need to include the steps of B inside A as well.

You don't include steps. You show if a use case uses another use case or extends it.

> You should NOT use UCDs [...] to try to illustrate the sequence of steps that must be performed in order to complete a task. Use Sequence diagrams to show these design features.
>
> [andrew.cmu.edu - UML Use Case Diagrams: Tips and FAQ](https://www.andrew.cmu.edu/course/90-754/umlucdfaq.html)

If A uses B then what is included in A is the knowledge that B exists. That doesn't mean that A knows what B knows. Keeping A from knowing that is likely why B exists in the first place. It's called abstraction. Use it to hide details in a nicely labeled box.

Comment: Thanks for the answer and link. My understanding was that first we have use case diagram. For each bubble (use case), it is possible to write sequence of steps and that would be our use case (where we identify primary actor, trigger, precondition, etc). Then I can choose one of these scenarios (use case could have exceptions) and that represents one sequence diagram

Comment: I see your point about not including B's contents. But going back to my previous comment, if use case -> use case steps (with several alterations and exceptions,) and each called scenario, then when I write step by step scenario, I just write contents of B? Lets assume B is authentication, and A is perform operation. In my scenario, I should just write B authenticates and then steps of A? Please help as I am really confused

Comment: See [Sequence diagram for Abstract and Derived class](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/359966/sequence-diagram-for-abstract-and-derived-class#359998)

Answer (score 0):

### In short

Don't repeat yourself (DRY). This applies also to use-case descriptions.

If A includes B, just refer to B as one of the steps. If B extends A, indicate in A's description the places where B would extend A ("extension points"). If A or B changes radically, you shouldn't have to rewrite the other.

### Some more explanations

The classical [use-case scenario](https://www.usability.gov/how-to-and-tools/methods/use-cases.html) (e.g. [Cockburn's](http://cis.bentley.edu/lwaguespack/CS360_Site/Downloads_files/Use%20Case%20Template%20%28Cockburn%29.pdf)'s template) provides a detailed step-by-step description, with the basic flow of the scenario, as well as alternate flows (variants,  error/exception processing, etc...):

- Included use-cases are independent and are always performed when the including use-case is performed.  The usual practice is to refer to included use-cases in a specific step.  The name of the included use-case could be highlighted in the wording (using exactly the title of the other use-case).
- Extending use-cases are optional behavior that would could either be performed as an optional step,  or correspond to one of the alternative scenario, or even be interweaved with the extended use-case at several places.  The "extension points" are in the extended use-cases steps some placeholders for referring to the extending behavior:

The description of A and B's scenarios should be loosely coupled: it should be possible tochange one without having to rewrite the other.

***Remark**:  Scenario-based use-cases are somewhat outdated, since they rely on up-front in-depth analysis which are not agile friendly. Moreover they frequently constrain/predefine user-interface unnecessarily.  Modern approaches rely either on [use case 2.0](https://www.ivarjacobson.com/publications/white-papers/use-case-ebook), where slices replace scenario in a more agile way, or on [essential use-cases](http://www.mcs.vuw.ac.nz/research/object/Papers/euc-html/node4.html), which replace interaction scenarios with user-centered intents.*